# HTTP Post Request with Windows Phone Webclient C#

Tags: c#, http, post, windows-phone-8

I have a php file on my local server which looks like this: (The database variables are in the config.php and are correct!)

```
<?php

require_once "config.php";

try
{
    $con = new PDO("mysql:host=".$db_host.";dbname=".$db_name,$db_user,$db_password);
    $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: ".$e->getMessage();
    exit();
}   

if (empty($_POST["number"]) || !isset($_POST["number"]))
{
    echo "Error: no number!";
    exit();
}
else if (empty($_POST["password"]) || !isset($_POST["password"]))
{
    echo "Error: no password!";
    exit();
}
else
{
    $number = $_POST["number"];
    $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
    $salt = sha1($_POST["password"]);
}

if (!empty($_POST["login"]))
{
    $sql = $con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(`ID`) FROM ".$db_table_login_students." WHERE `number` = ? AND `password` = ? AND `salt` = ? AND user_deleted=0");
    $sql->bindParam(1, $number);
    $sql->bindParam(2, $password);
    $sql->bindParam(3, $salt);
    $sql->execute();
    if($sql->fetchColumn() > 0) 
    {
        $login = array('Login' => 'Yes');
        echo json_encode($login);
        $_sql = $con->prepare("UPDATE ".$db_table_login_students." SET last_login=NOW() WHERE number = ?");
        $_sql->bindParam(1, $matrikelnummer);
        $_sql->execute();
        exit();
    } 
    else 
    {
        $login = array('Login' => 'No');
        echo json_encode($login);
        exit();
    }
}

?>
```

And now I want to make a HTTP Post Request with Windows Phone in C# and it looks now like this:

```
void PostJsonRequestWebClient() 
    { 
        WebClient webclient = new WebClient(); 
        Uri uristring = null; 
        uristring = new Uri("http://localhost/login.php?"); 
        webclient.Headers["ContentType"] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"; 
        string WebUrlRegistration = ""; 
        string JsonStringParams = "login=yes&number=4340490&password=test"; 
        webclient.UploadStringCompleted += wc_UploadStringCompleted; 
        webclient.UploadStringAsync(uristring, "POST", JsonStringParams); 
    } 
    private void wc_UploadStringCompleted(object sender, UploadStringCompletedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        try 
        { 

            if (e.Result != null) 
            { 
                string response = e.Result.ToString(); 
                textblock1.Text = response;
            } 
        } 
        catch 
        { 
        } 
    }
```

The login data with number and password are correct in my database. When I make a Get request instead of a Post I became as answer from the php script "{Login:Yes}". But when I make a Post request like the one above I became "Error: no number!". So I think the Post query string is false, but I find nothing. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the HTTP Header should be `Content-Type` instead of `ContentType`.